# Returning reference to struct

Tags: c++, struct, reference, operator-overloading

Using overloaded `[]` operator , we can set a value of element inside container. E.g

```
class Example{
public:
  Example(){
     arr = new int[10];
  }
  int operator [] ( unsigned int i) const{
        return arr[i];
  }
  int & operator [] ( unsigned int i){
        return arr[i];
  }
private:
  int *arr[];
}
```

So using

```
Example a;
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 2;
```

We can set the value of elements. Is it possible to do something like this with struct? If we didnt have array of int but vector of structs. e.g

```
 struct Test{
       int value;
       int index;
       Test( int a , int b){
          value = a;
          index = b;
       }
 }

 class Example{
 public:

       Example(){

       }
       int operator [] ( unsigned int i) const{
          return a[i].value;
       }
       Test & operator [] ( unsigned int i){
          Test a(0, i );
          one.push_back(a);
          return a -> value;
       }
private:
       vector<Test> a;
        }

Example a;
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    a[2] = 2;
```

How can i change the the value property of returned struct same way as changing/setting value using typical int container?

Comment: i would like to keep the syntax using just a[0] = 10;

Comment: Your second example is strange as you have typo/invalid stuff. what is `one` ? `return a -> value;` is not a `Test&`, you hide member `a`...

Comment: oh fixed the typo , thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you'd like to achieve, but maybe you want to give your struct an overloaded constructor and overloaded assignment operator, both taking an int, and a conversion operator to int, so that your structs will behave like ints in assignment and construction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The code has an error: `return a -> value;` returns an int, whereas the function `operator[](unsigned int i)` says it will return a reference to `Test`. You could instead return `one[one.length()-1]` so that you can say `example[0]->value = 1;`, where `example` is of type `Example`?

The statement `example[0]` is a call to `operator[](unsigned int i)` which returns a reference to `one[0]`, whose type is a reference to `Test`.

It is perfectly valid to define `operator[]` to return an int, and implement it the way you did above. But that's highly unintuitive; I would certainly find it very confusing because the operator [] usually returns an element of a container, not a field of an element of a container. Better to define a separate function with self-explanatory name for that, for example `int& getValue(unsigned int);` for the `value` field and `int& getIndex(unsigned int)` for the `index` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct Test {
    int value;
    int index;
    Test(int a, int b) {
        value = a;
        index = b;
    }
};

class Example {
public:
    Example() {}
    int operator [] (unsigned int i) const {
        return _a[i].value;
    }
    int & operator [] (unsigned int i) {
        Test a(0, i);
        _a.push_back(a);
        return _a[i].value;
    }
private:
    vector<Test> _a;
};

int main() {
    Example a;
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    a[2] = 2;
    return 0;
}
```